# Keep update history in Java + mysql project

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm developing `Java Web` JSF and `Hibernate` (DB `MySQL`). I have a table with the product fields (`id`, `name`, `description` and `price`), suppose that was saved a record any `(1, 'cd', 'bee gees', 11.90)`. Once saved the User will change the registry to `(1 'dvd' 'bee gees', 15.90)`. However, a new registration will be saved in a new line (or new table) to keep track of all the changes linked to the product code 1. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Are you saving new record on any changes to existing one?

Comment: Yes. A new recording for each change.

Comment: Then you can do one thing, you create one more table for product_fields_history (same as product_fields). First time when you insert to product_fields table just insert same record to product_fields_history and on updating product_fields insert new record to product_fields_history. Latest change will be in product_fields and complete history will be in product_fields_history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Hibernate Envers for auditing and tracking revision history in my previous project(s).

It's simple. Update revision history just by adding `@Audited` annotation in your entity class and retrieve change history using AuditReader.

Go through [Hibernate Envers Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) for detailed info.